# server_name in nginx.conf seems to be ignored

Tags: nginx

I've got a domain name, let's say example.com that point to my server. And my nginx.conf is:

```
upstream domain {
    server 127.0.0.1:8002; 
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name <example.com>;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    keepalive_timeout    15;
```

During development, I want to deactivate example.com. I replace it by `<different_name>`.

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name <different_name>;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    keepalive_timeout    15;
```

It works fine as expected with `<different_name>` but it still continues responding to `<example.com>`. And I can't figure out why. I'd like nginx to not respond at all on `<example.com>`.

Naturally I didn't forget to restart services as gunicorn and nginx.

Edit: It may be a duplicated post as suggested. In my opinion the way the problem is exposed in the post you mentioned is confused. Even the title is not clear. "nginx open reverse proxy" What does it mean seriously? I tried to expose my problem which has a similar solution in clear terms keeping in mind that it could / should be reusable and much more explicit to everyone.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/690242/211028

Comment: Also consired change DNS for `domain.com` not to point to your IP

Comment: The way the problem is exposed in the post you mentioned is confused to me. Even the title is not clear. "nginx open reverse proxy" What does it mean seriously?  I tried to expose it in clear terms keeping in mind that it could / should be reusable and much more explicit to everyone.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In short: by removing the production domainname requests for that domain do not get blocked, they will go to default server.

Paraphrased from the [manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html):

> Nginx tests only the request’s header field “Host” to determine which server the request should be routed to. If its value does not match any server name, or the request does not contain this header field at all, then nginx will route the request to the default server. Unless explicitly configured with `default_server` the default server is the *first* one.

You could create a minimal default server that either returns a default page or an error message e.g.:

```
server {
    listen      80 default_server;
    server_name _ ;
    return 503  "No server is currently configured for the requested host." ;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about the default_server. But I changed your proposition since it raises a conf error. Instead, I just return a 444. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the `server_name` direcrive is not needed.

Comment: note that you need quotes around the second parameter to the return statement

Comment: config is missing a `return 503  "No server is currently configured for the requested host." ;` can't edit because it needs 6 chars at least